# JavaScript and localStorage problems

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Here is a quick example that should (but it doesn't work for some reason).

```
function clearSave()
{
    var c = confirm("Are you sure you want to reset the current game?");

    if (c==true)
    {
        localStorage.setItem("saved","false");
        location.reload();
    }
}

function save()
{
    localStorage.setItem("saved","true");
    setTimeout(save,1000);
}

function load()
{
    if (localStorage.getItem("saved") == "true")
    {
        alert("Game Loaded");
    }
    else {
        save();
    }
}
```

When the page loads the load function is called. And when the user clicks a button to reset stuff the clearSave function is called.

But after the page is reloaded after the clearSave function is called the alert shows, meaning that the "saved" item is set to "true" somehow.

Any clues?

Comment: Why do you call the save function within the load function?

Comment: What is the purpose of `setTimeout(save,1000);` in `function save()`?

Comment: @pttsky probably to emulate the time it takes to save.

Comment: @pttsky Obviously to keep saving/updating the cookie every second...

Comment: Because there are more values in it and when the page restarts I want them all to be reset as well. Just to overwrite everything I use in localStorage.

Comment: I removed the setTimeout thingy and now everything works... but why?

Comment: coz u were calling the same function twice

Comment: Which function? I could only possibly call the save function twice. But this shouldn't matter at all. Obviously it is called after location.reload() which is strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setTimeout(save,1000);
```

The above code is causing the error, you need to use some other strategy based on your needs

```
function save()
{
    localStorage.setItem("saved","true");
    //Below line needs to be updated
    setTimeout(save,1000);
}
```